# Pycharm does not recognize pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pycharm, pyodbc

I want to acces an mysql server via a python script. Unfortunately it seems like pip does not install the pyodbc module correctly, because I get the "Module not found"-Error, when trying to import pydbc. But the module is listed as installed in the project interpreter.

Can somebody help me fixing this or recommend another module to reach out to an mssql server via python.
THANKS!

Comment: Have you tried `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ...` ?

Comment: Tried and did not work, Problem still the same